# What happened to Curtis?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-blues-brothers

In "The Blues Brothers", when Jake and Elwood are escaping through the trapdoor they wave to Curtis and then after that we never see him again for the rest of the Film and he's not even mentioned. What happened to him?

Answer (score 4):

As far as the original movie goes, it's implied that **nothing** happens to him.

> Jake and Elwood are escaping through the trapdoor they wave to Curtis and then after that we never see him again for the rest of the Film

Actually, the last we see of him is during the final *Jailhouse Rock* closing song. The rest of the band is in jail but Curtis seems to be back in in his basement.

It seems likely therefore, that he escaped any consequences of his involvement in the Blue Brothers escape.

Subsquent to the movie, it is revealed in *Blues Brothers 2000* that Curtis has passed away during the 18 years between the movies.